# text object to string in jquery

Tags: jquery

My Dom has this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="current_time" value="27 Mar 14 11:29:57 GMT-04:00">
```

I assign a variable to the value like this:

```
g_current_time = $('#current_time').attr("value");
```

when console logging  g_current_time I get the expected:

```
27 Mar 14 11:29:57 GMT-04:00
```

but when trying to display the contents of the variable in the Dom it displays as [Object Text].

How do I need to convert it to a string?

The variable is concatenated into a string which is in turn diaplayed in the DOM;

```
stat.innerText = "  Shutdown request on channel " + channel_identifier + " @ " + g_current_time + " accepted.";
```

at this point console logging stat.innerText shows:

```
Shutdown request on channel 1 @ [object Text] accepted.
```

Comment: How are you trying to display the contents of that variable in the DOM?

Comment: Agree, the problem is with however you're trying to display the variable in the DOM. Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xp4r6/

Comment: I updated the original question to show more detail about how it is concatenated before the result of the concatenation is shown on screen. It is after this concatenation that I first see the issue.

Comment: What if you try $('#current_time').val()

Comment: Looks fine here -> http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/u2z84/

Answer (score 0):

Please use .val() as below and it seems to work fine.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/u2z84/)

JS:

```
$(function(){
    var g_current_time = $('#current_time').val();
    console.log("  Shutdown request on channel 1 @ " + g_current_time + " accepted.");
});
```